# How do I start a application and close it immediately in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, process, psexec

As part of a automated test case, I have to start an application(for example notepad) and close it without any user intervention. The executable I use to launch this application should be called in System account and to achieve this I use PSExec utility. So the call looks somewhat like this :

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = "PsExec.exe";
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.Arguments = " -i -s " + myExecutable.exe + " -application notepad.exe";
            Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)
exeProcess.WaitForExit();
```

The above code starts notepad and waits until it is closed, only then will I get a proper exit code from myExecutable.exe

Some of the ways that I tried :

Using timer with WaitForExit and Kill, this doesn't close notepad but exists the program with 0 and -1 respectively, maybe because I'm killing the process PSExec and not myexecutable.

Is there a way to close Notepad.exe automatically? Or even an API that can be used to run a process in System account(So I can get rid of PSExec entirely).

Comment: To close an application with a main window you can call `CloseMainWindow`, although that may prompt the user to save changes. There are no changes in your case though.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_CloseMainWindow

Comment: try this [article](https://alperguc.blogspot.com/2008/11/c-process-processgetprocessesbyname.html)

Comment: Doesn't sound like a useful test case. But if you really need what you're asking for then `CreateProcess` (or `CreateProcessAsUser`), followed by `TerminateProcess` is what you're looking for. Again, doesn't appear to be of any practical use, but there you have it.